# For UDP traffic reverse route is required or not

Tags: routing, networking

when compared to TCP protocol, UDP is non reliable protocol no knowledgement packet is required for previous packet before sending new packet . so in this case reverse route configuration is required for UDP traffic ?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question does not keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on the application.  Most applications are two-way; A sends data, and B replies.  If the application expects a reply from the receiving host, then Yes, a reverse route is required.